# How to connect to a kernel in virtual environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

I created a virtual environment successfully from windows command prompt, but when I open jupyter notebook I get a message "A connection to the notebook server could not be established. the notebook will continue trying to reconnect. check your network connection or notebook server configuration." Can someone advise whether I should upgrade/degrade any packages or is there any other solution. Thanks.

```
Package           Version
----------------- -------
backcall          0.2.0
colorama          0.4.4
debugpy           1.4.1
decorator         5.0.9
ipykernel         6.0.3
ipython           7.26.0
ipython-genutils  0.2.0
jedi              0.18.0
jupyter-client    6.1.12
jupyter-core      4.7.1
matplotlib-inline 0.1.2
parso             0.8.2
pickleshare       0.7.5
pip               21.2.2
prompt-toolkit    3.0.19
Pygments          2.9.0
python-dateutil   2.8.2
pywin32           301
pyzmq             22.2.1
setuptools        49.2.1
six               1.16.0
tornado           6.1
traitlets         5.0.5
wcwidth           0.2.5
```

Comment: in your environment: python -m ipykernel install --user --name your-env --display-name "the_name_you_want_displayed"

Comment: @warped do you want to check the error logs?

Comment: this code should register the ipykernel for your environment

Comment: Still I'm not able to connect to the kernel. I tried: python -m ipykernel install --user --name anprsys --display-name ANPR

Comment: does it say successfully installed kernelspec when you execute the line in your environment in your command prompt?

Comment: Yes. (anprsys) D:\Computer Vision Projects\ANPR>python -m ipykernel install --user --name anprsys --display-name ANPR
Installed kernelspec anprsys in C:\Users\mycomp\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\anprsys

Comment: ok, that was all I know, so if that doesn't work I cannot help :(

Comment: That's fine no problem :)